# Angular: Generate hyperlink inside ts file

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to generate a hyperlink in side the component (in .ts file) in side a function using for loop. I know I can do that by using *ngFor loop in the template.
For example -

```
    <div *ngFor="let rec of item.Records; let k = index;">
    <a [routerLink]="['<url>']"
        [queryParams]="{ id: <itemID>, code: <code>} 
    </a>
   </div>
```

How can I do the same thing inside the .ts file inside a function.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can use for each - this should get you pretty close to where you want to go

```
url: any;
    recordArray.forEach((record) => {
      if(record.url){
     return url as any
    })
```

Comment: Thank you chris, However, I am trying to construct the entire anchor tag inside the for loop, by passing the query parameters  also.

Comment: so then concact the url = http://yoururl + '/' + record  - in your for each loop - its an example.  you can then return it that way

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use hyperlink at component level, then you can use innerHTML property.
Example:

Template.html

```
<span [innerHTML]='messageText'></span>
```

Component.ts

```
messageText = "<a href='http://www.google.com'>Open Google</a>"
```

Expected message display:

Open Google.

Actual message display:

[Open Google](http://www.google.com)

If you want to continue with Template then this could help you.

Component.ts

```
export class AppComponent  {
  
  data=[
    {
      name:"Facebook",
      url:"www.Facebook.org"
    },
    {
      name:"Google",
      url:"www.google.com"
    },
    {
      name:"Twitter",
      url:"www.Twitter.com"
    }
  ]
  }
```

Template.html

```
<div *ngFor = "let item of data"> 
  <a [attr.href]="item.url">
   {{item.name}}
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I need to create that in the component file, since I Am generating the html in a function dynamically